# How front-end works with Event Driver Architecture

Tags: frontend, microservices, event-driven, event-driven-design

I'm more experienced in the backend layer, lately I'm studying micro-services and Event Driver Architecture, I've done some searches on WEB, but don't found out how this exactly works on the front-end layer, for example, let's assume that you make a request HTTP to a API gateway, after this API gateway send message to a message broker, like Kafka for example, and then spread to some micro-services, but in this scenario, how it works to back the response to front-end? does the front-end has some kind of listener to some response message of this API gateway?